# Create MySQL Statement into Spark SQL Statement

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

How do I convert this MySQL statement into a spark SQL statement?

```
set_engagement_sql = """ UPDATE """ + my_table_name + """ SET 
                Engagement = CASE 
                    WHEN LinkedAccountId = '1234567890101' THEN '800000046406'
                    WHEN LinkedAccountId = '1234567890102' THEN '803000006453'
                    WHEN LinkedAccountId IN ('1234567890103', '12345678901014') THEN '800000043270'
                    WHEN LinkedAccountId IN ('1234567890105', '1234567890106') THEN '400000008426'
                    WHEN LinkedAccountId IN ('1234567890106', '1234567890107') THEN '807000000401'
                    WHEN LinkedAccountId IN ('1234567890108', '1234567890109', '1234567890110', '1234567890111') THEN '808000000298'
                    WHEN LinkedAccountId IN ('1234567890112', '1234567890113', '1234567890114', '1234567890115') THEN '800000047650'
                    WHEN LinkedAccountId IN ('1234567890116', '1234567890117', '1234567890118','1234567890119', '1234567890120','1234567890121', '123456789022', '1234567890123', '1234567890124', '1234567890125') THEN '800000039768'
                    WHEN LinkedAccountId IN ('1234567890126', '1234567890126', '1234567890127', '1234567890128', '1234567890129', '1234567890128', '1234567890129', '1234567890130', '1234567890131', '1234567890131',  '1234567890132', '1234567890133') THEN '400000008692'
                    WHEN LinkedAccountId IN ('1234567890134', '1234567890135', '1234567890136', '1234567890137',  '1234567890138', '1234567890138', '1234567890139', '1234567890140', '1234567890141',  '1234567890142', '1234567890143', '1234567890144', '1234567890145', '1234567890146') THEN '400000008378' 
                    ELSE '800000039768'
                END
                WHERE Engagement IS NULL OR Engagement RLIKE '^[a-zA-Z]'; """
```

I tried doing this in pyspark, but it's throwing off the results. I think this might work better if I can get it working.

Comment: can you please add some data sample for same ?